# Mobx does not see changes done inside setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have a screen like that

```
const ScreenA = observer(() => {
  const { userStore } = useRootStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      userStore.ping();
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  console.log(userStore.pingResult);

  retunr <></>
});
```

And store

```
class UserStore {
  pingResult = null;

  ping = async () => {
    console.log('ping');
    const pingResult = await this.userService.ping();
    runInAction(() => {
      this.pingResult = pingResult;
    });
  };
}
```

The problem is `console.log(userStore.pingResult);` works only once — I guess, observer just can't see that store has been updated. Tried to JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pingResult)) to make sure that pingResult is completely new, but it didn't work. At the same time `console.log('ping')` works as expected — every 3 seconds.

Comment: What type is `pingResult`? If it is a primitive value and it does not change then it's expected that observer is not updated because value didn't change

Comment: @Danila it is and object

Comment: Then you forgot something crucial, like `makeAutoObservable` or something. I've recreated your code here and it works https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-72986196-dze644

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make your user store observable. Otherwise it is just a plain JS instance that is not observable for mobx

```
class UserStore {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  // ...
}
```